# How Can I prevent of decreasing the equation number size?

Tags: equations, fontsize

I have a problem. when I use the code `{\small some formula }` the equation numbers become small. what can I do?

Comment: it is almost always advisable to use a multiline display rather than shrink the font size, but it all depends on other constraints you might have.

Comment: It would look weird to have a "regular-size" equation number next to a "small" or, shudder, "tiny" displayed formula. If you can't stand the "small" equation numbers, you need to find another way to typeset the formula. You may want to start by acquainting yourself with the [amsmath](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/amsmath.html) package and, in particular, its environments for multi-line equations.

Comment: Can you show us a complete example that replicates your behaviour? That is, elaborate on what you mean by `{\small some formula}`. Are you using `{\small \begin{equation} some formula \end{equation}}`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good idea, but if you insist, here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \text{\small$\displaystyle
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    $}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. "This is not a good idea" -- the understatement of the day! :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `amsmath`, this adaptation of the `\maketag@@@` command will ensure that all tags are the same size.  (it will someday be incorporated in `amsmath`; it has been on the list of desirable adjustments for many years.)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}%
\makeatother
```

this ignores the question of whether changing the size of the display itself is a good idea or not.  (it really should be avoided if at all possible, but it's not always possible.)